# UWP Nullable Aggregate Battery Information

Tags: uwp

In my UWP application I am trying to get an Aggregate Battery Information like this:

```
var aggBattery = Windows.Devices.Power.Battery.AggregateBattery;
    BatteryReport report = aggBattery.GetReport();
    aggBattery.ReportUpdated += AggBattery_ReportUpdated;
    int? fullCapacity = report.FullChargeCapacityInMilliwattHours;
    int? remainingCapacity = report.RemainingCapacityInMilliwattHours;
```

Unfortunately, it seems like the current battery controller does not fit the Microsoft's one (it's CHUWI 12" tablet), and it returns null values (like in MSDN describes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/get-battery-info). The only Charging/Discharging info is real.
How can I get the battery information in this case (I mean charging percentage)?

Comment: Looks like a (drivers) issue with your tablet. Look for updates, they're not always installed automatically. Otherwise, try to get along with what you do have (individual batteries?).

Comment: Could you please tell us your OS version and targeted SDK version?

Comment: O.k., OS version is: Windows 10 Home, Version 1607, OS build 14393.576;

Comment: Target: Universal Windows, Min, version: Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10586), Target version: Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393)